# Checking out Google Code using Tortoise

Tags: tortoise-svn, google-code

Can anyone explain to me how to use Tortoise to obtain this project?

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/youtube-jsonc-sample/?repo=samples

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) repository, so you'd have to use [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/), not TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/download/index.html).
- Create a directory somewhere with the name you want (e.g. `google-api-java-client samples`).
- Right click on it, and select `TortoiseHg > Clone...`

[image: the selection]

- On **Source**, copy paste the URL of the repository you want to clone, in your case `https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/`.
- Click `Clone`.